# Angular SVG gradient fill not rendering

Tags: angular, svg

Initial apologies as I am not entirely familiar with all the exact terminology for what I'm trying to do: I am attempting to render an SVG icon using Angular (12).  A (trimmed down) version of my SVG (`discover.svg`) is:

```
<svg id="discover" viewBox="0 0 38.257 24.47" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="grad2" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="17.278" cy="10.17" r="2.906"
      gradientTransform="matrix(-1.320119, -1.659667, 1.942541, -1.545116, 24.895274, 56.860206)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(238, 143, 48);" />
      <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color: rgb(255, 80, 0);" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color: rgba(40, 14, 6, 1)" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <path id="Path_14883" data-name="Path 14883" d="M18.366-198.8l37.986,0v24.192H18.37Z" transform="translate(-18.231 198.943)" fill="#fff" />
  <path id="Path_14884" data-name="Path 14884" d="M87.316-135.9s-10.38,7.325-29.39,10.6h29.39Z" transform="translate(-49.33 149.496)"
    style="fill: rgb(255, 80, 0);" />
  <circle style="fill: url(/assets/img/icons/discover.svg#grad2);" cx="20.063" cy="10.251" r="2.906" />
</svg>
```

The Angular component code that renders the icon is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-icon',
  template: `
    <svg width="1em" height="1em">
      <use [attr.href]="getIconUrl()"></use>
    </svg>
  `
})
```

`getIconUrl()` gets the right URL to pull in the SVG (`http://localhost:8080/assets/img/icons/discover.svg#discover`), and the SVG is displayed with the orange "swoosh" at the bottom, but I can't get the radial gradient fill to display - it's just empty where it should be.  The fill URL looks right in chrome dev tools (`http://localhost:8080/assets/img/icons/discover.svg#grad2`) but nothing displays.

If there's anything else I need to provide - please just let me know.

Here's the full HTML as it renders in Chrome:

```
<my-icon ng-reflect-icon="discover" title="discover">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em">
    <use href="http://localhost:8080/assets/img/icons/discover.svg#discover">
      #shadow-root (closed)
      <svg id="discover" viewBox="0 0 38.257 24.47" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path id="Path_14883" data-name="Path 14883" d="M18.366-198.8l37.986,0v24.192H18.37Z" transform="translate(-18.231 198.943)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <path id="Path_14884" data-name="Path 14884" d="M87.316-135.9s-10.38,7.325-29.39,10.6h29.39Z" transform="translate(-49.33 149.496)" style="fill: rgb(255, 80, 0);"></path>
        <circle style="fill: url(/assets/img/icons/discover.svg#grad2);" cx="20.063" cy="10.251" r="2.906"></circle>
      </svg>
    </use>
  </svg>
</my-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the circle you can directly refer to the radialGradiant id.

```
<circle style="fill: url(#grad2);" cx="20.063" cy="10.251" r="2.906" />
```

Comment: Angular creates a base tag to the document, so if I don't qualify the URL, it just tries to point to ```http://localhost:8080/#grad2```